# How to size the texture to occupy only a portion of a QQuickItem UI

Tags: qt, opengl, opengl-es, qquickitem, qsgclipnode

I have overriden `updatePaintNode` in the following way to draw an OpenGL texture on a `QQuickItem` derived class called `MyQQuickItem` here.

```
QSGNode *MyQQuickItem::updatePaintNode(QSGNode * oldNode, QQuickItem::UpdatePaintNodeData * /*updatePaintNodeData*/) 
{
  QSGSimpleTextureNode * textureNode = static_cast<QSGSimpleTextureNode *>(oldNode);

  if (!textureNode) {
    textureNode = new QSGSimpleTextureNode();
  }

  QSize size(800, 800);
  // myTextureId is a GLuint here
  textureNode.reset(window()->createTextureFromId(myTextureId, size));
  textureNode->setTexture(my_texture);
  textureNode->markDirty(QSGBasicGeometryNode::DirtyMaterial);

  QSizeF myiewport = boundingRect().size();

  qreal xOffset = 0;
  qreal yOffset = 10;

  textureNode->setRect(xOffset, yOffset, myViewport.width(), myViewport.height());
  return textureNode;
}
```

This renders the texture content well but covers the whole of my `MyQQuickItem` UI.

**How can reduce the bottom margin of the texture to say fit 80% of the height** of `MyQQuickItem`.
I want to **render the texture to a portion of** `MyQQuickItem` & leave the rest blank or black? Is that possible within `updatePaintNode`.

**Note** that the texture size is not the UI window size here. My texture size is *800 by 800*. Whereas the UI window size is different and depends on the screen.

Comment: found the solution to what I am trying to do & posted & answer. Other answers which can give more insight into how this `QSGSimpleTextureNode` works, are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this:

Changing `myViewport.height()` gives the required end in *Y* direction one wishes to set. Similarly, changing `myViewport.width()` gives the required end in *X* direction one wishes to set.

4 parameters in TextureNode's `setRect` can stretch & fit the texture in the way one wishes within a portion of the QQuickItem.